# Compare and merging 2 arrays of type myClass in one array of the same type

Tags: java, arrays, json

I’m trying to merge 2 arrays that have json URL data fetched into them, these 2 urls have 1 shared field called “bay_id” this field matches in 3080 items. URL 1 has 3080 data and URL 2 has 7100 data. I did compare if the the “bay_id” in URL 1 have the same “bay_id” in URL 2 then merge. The problem I’m having with my for loops it sets the same “bay_id” for all the indexes. In addition to myClass called Post have setter and getter methods for all the wanted fields. 
My code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < url_1.length; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < url_2.length; j++) {

                    if (url_2[j].getBayId_2().equals(url_1[i].getBayId_1()) ) {

                        for (int k = 0; k < mergedURLs.length; k++) {

                            mergedURLs[k].setBayId_1(url_1[i].getBayId_1());
                            mergedURLs[k].setStatus(url_1[i].getStatus());
                            mergedURLs[k].setLat(url_1[i].getLat());
                            mergedURLs[k].setLon(url_1[i].getLon());
                            mergedURLs[k].setBayId_2(url_2[j].getBayId_2());
                           //and so on for all the fields 
                    }//-------End if statment 
                }//------End for loop url_2
            }//-------end for loop url_1
        }//-------end for loop 


        for (int z = 0; z < mergedURLs.length; z++) {
            System.out.println("New bay_id" + mergedURLs[z].getBayId_1());
        }
```

Comment: What do you think that inner-most loop does? Oh yeah, it updates **ALL** `mergedURLs` entries with the same values. --- Perhaps you meant to *add* a new object with values merged from `url_1[i]` and `url_2[j]` to the *next* slot in the `mergedURLs` array?

Comment: Correct I knew the loop is assign all of the indexes to the same value, I meant to add all the fields in url_1 and all the fields in url_2 in new array is below:
index 0 have the fields from url_1 and the fields from url_2 
index 1 have the fields from url_1 and the fields from url_2 
index 2 have the fields from url_1 and the fields from url_2 
and so on...

Comment: Wouldn't using a `Set` (if order must be preserved a `LinkedHashSet`) be way easier? Create the set out of your first array then add the urls of the second array (which only succeeds if the weren't duplicates) and if need be convert that back to an array. (or if you actually need to merge the objects use a `Map` instead).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this. I created a test class called `MyUrl` which represents the objects in both the arrays (`urls1` and `urls2`) and the merged array. This `MyUrl` class implements `java.lang.Comparable` interface - this is for sorting the `url1` array (more details follow).

*The process of merging:* I am assuming the `urls2` array has more data then the `urls1`. First I created an empty `ArrayList<MyUrl>` which will have all the urls - the merged ones. Then *sort* the `urls1` array - this is for searching the `urls1` array by `bayId` from the `urls2` - the `Arrays.binarySearch` method is used.

Now, iterate the `urls2` within a for-loop and search the `urls1` for the match of each `bayId` (of `urls2`). Once a matching `bayId` is found the data is merged and stored in the `ArrayList`, otherwise just the `urls2` data is stored. By the end of the for-loop the `ArrayList` will have the merged data.

The sample program below can be compiled and run. See the data in the input arrays and the printed output from the merged `ArrayList`. The matched and merged `MyUrl`s have a "MERGED" flag.

The example code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CompareAndMerge {

    // Some test data: two sets of url data. One with lesser urls1 and
    // the other usrls2. Note there are some matching bayIds in both arrays.
    private static MyUrl [] urls1 =  {new MyUrl("abc", "yes"), new MyUrl("xyz", "no"),
                    new MyUrl("url", "true"), new MyUrl("lmn", "false")};
    private static MyUrl [] urls2 =  {new MyUrl("abc", "yes"), new MyUrl("xyz", "no"),
                    new MyUrl("cat", "else"), new MyUrl("rat", "if"),
                    new MyUrl("url", "true"), new MyUrl("lmn", "false")};

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        // The urls1 array is sorted by bayId to allow a binary search -
        // the searching of array by bayId.
        // Also, see the method getMatchingUrl()
        Arrays.sort(urls1, null); // null indicates the elements implement comparable

        // The list is to store the merged urls from bouth the arrays
        List<MyUrl> merged = new ArrayList<>();

        // Iterate over the urls2 (the array with more elements) and store
        // the merged data in the list. The data is merged when there
        // is a match with bayId otherwise just the urls2 data is stored.
        for (MyUrl url2 : urls2) {
            MyUrl url1 = getMatchingUrl(url2);
            if (url1 == null) {
                // no bayId match found
                // store the url2 to merged urls
                merged.add(url2);
            }
            else {
                // found a matching bayId in urls1
                // merge the url1 to url2 data
                // for example: url2.setBayId2(url1.getBayId2()); etc.
                url2.setMerged("MERGED");
                merged.add(url2);
            }
        }

        // Result shows matching bayId's urls are merged.
        // The output has all the urls from both the arrays.
        System.out.println(merged);
    }

    private static MyUrl getMatchingUrl(MyUrl url2) {
        int urls1Index = Arrays.binarySearch(urls1, url2, null); // null indicates comparable elements
        if (urls1Index < 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return urls1[urls1Index];
    }   
}

class MyUrl implements Comparable<MyUrl> {
    private String bayId;
    private String status;
    private String merged;
    public MyUrl(String s1, String s2) {
        bayId = s1;
        status = s2;
    }
    public void setBayId(String s) {
        bayId = s;
    }
    public String getBayId() {
        return bayId;
    }
    public void setStatus(String s) {
        status = s;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setMerged(String s) {
        merged = s;
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return bayId + ":" + status + ":" + merged;
    }

    /*
     * Implemented method of java.lang.Comparable
     */
    @Override public int compareTo(MyUrl url) {
        return this.bayId.compareTo(url.getBayId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, i appreciate it.